# Question about a sentence inn Griffiths QM book about The Free Electron Gas on pg-225

Tags: quantum-mechanics

[image: The Free Electron Gas, giving the volume of each state]

It is stated that "each intersection point represents a distinct(one-particle) stationary state."

My question is: The two adjacent intersection points(say, on $k_x$ axis) represent two distinct stationary states. Between them, $k_x$ will take non-integral values, which is not possible. It means that the states are confined to the points only. So the volume occupied by a state should be zero(as the volume of a point is). Then why is the volume of the block equal to the volume of each state when a distinct state can be only at 1 corner of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you want to find the density of states in k space. The question you are trying to answer is, "If I have a given volume in k space, how many points corresponding to allowed states will it contain?" By dividing the total volume by the total number of states contained in the volume, you get an effective volume per state.

This way of thinking is useful when you want to approximate an infinite sum over the states with an integral over all k space.

Comment: I thought about that. There are 8 points in one block of the volume $\frac{\pi^3}{l_xl_yl_z}$ with each point surrounded by 8 blocks thus contributing $\frac{1}{8}$ to each block. Total contribution by 8 points=8*(1/8)=1. The same method we used in solid state while studying fcc and bcc. But there were atoms which were identical to each other. In this case each point is distinct since it represents a different state. So how can we just combine their contributions? If my method or my thought is wrong please correct it.

Comment: You don't need to worry about figuring out whether you are assigning each distinct point its "true volume," because there is no such thing. Rather, we want to associate an average volume (which, because it is an average, does not depend on the particular state) with every allowed state.